# Ubuntu keeps scrolling down and typing '~' on its own

Tags: drivers, keyboard, devices, laptop, scrolling

For awhile now, while using my laptop running Ubuntu, it will constantly scroll down to the bottom of the page even while I'm trying to move up.

It also will sometimes constantly type ~! I've tried disabling both the key and the touchpad (using a mouse instead) but it hasn't worked.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Definitely sounds like a stuck key.